# Новинарний чи новинний?

Tags: вживання-слів, неологізми

Натрапила на оголошення "У консалтингову компанію, яка займається написанням текстів для різних сайтів, соціальних мереж, шукаємо автора текстів в новинарний відділ." Що то за слово - *новинарний*? Утворене від *новинар*? СУМ-11 не містить ані *новинар*, ані *новинарний*. Але пошук Гугл містить 10,7 тис. випадків вживання цього слова. Що воно означає і чому більш звичне *новинний* не влаштовує?

Comment: Судячи з профілю компанії, вони шукають не автора новин, а журналіста, тому "новинний" не підходить по смислу.

Comment: @ Artemix, а до чого по смислу підходить новинарний? Поясніть, будь ласка, значення цього прикметника, якщо ви його розумієте.

Comment: [Вікіпедія: журналіст (новинар)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82), [Словник синонімів: ЖУРНАЛІСТ газетяр, новинар, публіцист](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53398/264752.html), [Чиста мова: Новинар-журналіст](https://www.facebook.com/chystamova/posts/323369811152469). На мій погляд новинар це, скоріше, журналіст що пише про новини, але в останньому пості, здається, пропонують широко трактувати це слово.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Існування опозиції прикметників **новинний-новинарний** також має свою
>   базу в сучасному українському лексиконі, пор.: елемент і
>   елементний:елементарний, планета і планетний:планетарний. Щоправда,
>   прикметники з нарощеннями на суфікс в словотвірній нормі сучасної
>   української мови спираються на твірні іменники іншомовного походження
>   і в своїй структурі ніби «проявляють» на українському мовному ґрунті
>   основотвірні суфікси їхніх етимонів у мовах-джерелах запозичування, до
>   того ж саме прикметникам з такою ускладненою будовою властиві якісні
>   значення на відміну від простих прикметників з відносними значеннями.,
>   Отже, життєстійкість прикметника **новинарний** викликає сумніви.

[Н. Ф. КЛИМЕНКО, Є. А. КАРПІЛОВСЬКА, Л. П. КИСЛЮК ДИНАМІЧНІ ПРОЦЕСИ В СУЧАСНОМУ
УКРАЇНСЬКОМУ ЛЕКСИКОНІ](http://lib.movahistory.org.ua/Dynamichni_procesy.pdf)